# Is there any way optimize large list array?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, listview, react-native-maps

i am trying to build custom appointment calendar, array 28 days ( 28 rows) each row 36 item array then i am doing map to render.. each time it runs 1 day = 36 items (boxes) means 1008 times component renders.. now when i try to select a box, it takes lot of time to update because 1008 times it again renders, please need help on this.

[image: the calendar]

when i reduce rows it works good but a month contains atleast 28 days i have to run it for 28 times and each time 36 box creates by map, i want it to be quick when i select boxes

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way optimize large list array?

You could implement `react-virtualized` - so the elements that are not currently visible by user (are out of the viewport) will be not rendered - I know from my own experience that is just works great and the difference is strongly visible.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized

Also you could treat every *checkbox* as a separate component and wrap it with `React.memo` so it re-renders only if props have changed. Remember to wrap all the functions passed to it with `React.useCallback`.